# Web.Config Authorization for folder access

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, web-config

When managing access rules in the login module. Is there an explicit deny all at the end?

Let's say I have two roles: `Administrator` and `Member`

Administrators are allowed into the folder `iPhone` and Members are allowed in the folder `Blackberry`

I manage my rules and get the following code in each web.config:

```
"iPhone"
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrator" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>

"Blackberry"
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Member" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

But can Administrators access the Blackberry folder and Members the iPhone folder? Or do I need to add a rule saying `deny roles="Administrator"`in the Blackberry folder and `deny roles="Member"` in the iPhone folder?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean using an ASP.net application...

Add in a:

```
<deny users="*">
```

after your authorized users.

I think you should also be using `user` rather than `role`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

> When you create a new web application, all web.config settings (global, site and local) are merged together to form the configuration that's really in effect for this application. By default a local web.config does not contain an authorization section but inherits the one defined globally. So you alway end up with a  entry.

http://www.leastprivilege.com/ASPNETAuthorizationSettings.aspx

Comment: Well Ed and Ted might not be the right names, they do sound more like Users. But Administrator and Member would be better I presume?

Comment: and yes, I am using an asp.net application. So even if you allow a role to a folder, you still need to use <deny roles ="*"> ?

Comment: Yes, Administrators and Members would be groups. You need to specify users to groups so they can login. Check out the link I pasted.

Comment: @Tom: Yes you need to explicitly deny. When you create a new web application, all web.config settings (global, site and local) are merged together to form the configuration that's really in effect for this application. By default a local web.config does not contain an authorization section but inherits the one defined globally. So you alway end up with a <allow user="*" /> entry.

Comment: okay, thank you very much JD! So technically allowing users and roles to folders isn't necessary, only the denying them access?

Comment: @Tom: It depends what you want. The first matching rule is always parsed in the section, so if you deny="*" first, then allow roles the deny rule will take precedence.

Comment: I know, but if I say "Allow Members - Deny *" or "Deny Administrators" I get the same output right?

Comment: nope not quite... check out the links I pasted for clarification

Comment: In the first link it doesn't really give much extra information about this and in the second link he allows the role HR and denies access to all other users.

Comment: So if you have 2 roles: HR and Sales, denying HR or Sales to a folder means all other users can access it, like anonymous ones? I see where you're getting at! 
So allow to the ones you want, then deny to all other users, right?

Comment: Correct with your second statement.